# PHP Global Variable - Keep assigned value

Tags: php, html, forms, date, submit

I have the following declaration at the beginning of my PHP script:

```
$GLOBALS['monthselect'] = date('m');
$GLOBALS['yearselect'] = date('Y');
```

during the script I assign the following values:

```
$GLOBALS['monthselect'] = $_GET['mo'];
$GLOBALS['yearselect'] = $_GET['yr'];
```

Next, after a form submits, I want to redirect it to the same selection in GET. (This is all in the same PHP script)

```
header('Location: ?yr='. $GLOBALS['yearselect'] .'&mo=' . $GLOBALS['monthselect']);
```

Problem is, this always reloads the page with the date of today. Never the newly stored values. So always this output:

```
website.com/?yr=2013&mo=06
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide the places where do you set `$GLOBALS['monthselect'] = $_GET['mo'];` and `$GLOBALS['yearselect'] = $_GET['yr'];` Make sure they get executed..